# In which mission do you follow Joshua Kramer to his hideout?

Tags: watch-dogs

I just wanted to know in which mission aiden is supposed to infiltrate Joshua Kramer's hideout as shown in "Exposed" trailer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This never happens in the game within the main story and none of the side missions (that I know) are as detailed as the one in the "[Exposed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqoQG_XYF-8)" trailer.
Judging by how old the trailer is, my best bet is it got cut out of the game, or wasn't supposed to be in the game to begin with.

Comment: You do however enter the hideout as part of Act III, I believe.  The name of the ring leader is different as well, which you discover at the end of the Human Trafficking side missions.

Answer (score 0):

You never do, but he was not cut out of the game. He can be seen at the auction texting his wife and also at the brandon docks.